# Solving the system $2 x-3 y+\frac{1}{x y}=6$, $3 z-6 x+\frac{1}{x z}=2$, $6 y-2 z+\frac{1}{y z}=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

> Solve $$\begin{array}{l}
> 2 x-3 y+\frac{1}{x y}=6 \\
> 3 z-6 x+\frac{1}{x z}=2 \\
> 6 y-2 z+\frac{1}{y z}=3
> \end{array}$$

Notice that $$-2(2x-3y)-\frac{2}{3}(3z-6x)=6y-2z$$

So we get:
$$\frac{2}{xy}-12-\frac{4}{3}+\frac{2}{3xz}=3-\frac{1}{yz}$$
So we get
$$\frac{2}{xy}+\frac{2}{3xz}+\frac{1}{yz}=\frac{49}{3}$$
$\implies$
$$\frac{3x+2y+6z}{xyz}=49$$
Any approach from here?